# Cannot adjust vertical spacing for snapping to baseline grid

Tags: css, cross-browser, spacing, typography, baseline

There is [a demo page](http://neo.chebykin.ru/lab/imposition/) with two block-level elements, namely `h1` and `h2`. I try to put all baselines exactly on the grid in a cross-browser way, but I fail with the second heading.

For the `h1`, I have experimented with `margin-top` and found that its value can be set between `1.5px` and `1.85px`—then the heading snaps to baselines in all browsers.

But trying to find a similar range for the `margin-top` of `h2`, I reached a deadlock. In most browsers (e.g. Chrome or Safari) the appropriate range turned out to be `4px` to `4.99px`. But in Firefox on Windows (and only on Windows) it is `3px` to `3.99px`. So there is no intersecting subrange for possible values of margin. If the heading is perfectly snapped in one browser, it misses by exactly 1 pixel in the other.

Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Try this: https://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm/

Comment: @Toby, this approach is good in theory, but in practice it leads to the same ±1-pixel scatter in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Firefox on Mac behaves the same way as it does on Windows, but on Linux it treates spacing differently. So until a cross-browser solution is found, I’m afraid I have to use CSS hacks to target Firefox on Windows and Mac specifically:

```
@media screen and (-moz-windows-theme) {
  … CSS for Windows goes here …
}

@supports(-moz-osx-font-smoothing:auto) {
  … CSS for Mac goes here …
}
```